# MKStoreKit purchase error

Tags: ios, mkstorekit

I'm still struggling with MKStoreKit.

There is a button called "buyAction" who has to launch the in-app purchase process. I've tried to implement it following tutorial advice but it still doesn't work :

```
- (IBAction)buyAction:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"buyFeature")
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"PBonnet.TOEIC3.Package1"
                                onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature, NSData*purchasedReceipt, NSArray* availableDownloads)
 { package1bought=1;
     NSLog(@"success");

 }
                               onCancelled:^
 { NSLog(@"failed purchase");

 }]; 

}
```

On the `onComplete`line, I've got 2 error messages : "Parameter name omitted" and "Expected expression".

Thanks for your help.

Cheers

**EDIT** of the `onComplete` line as supposed by matt. Now, the log is showing "buyFeature" but nothing after. App Store doesn't launch. Log shows this error message :

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: PBonnet.TOEIC3 has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the header for MKStoreManager. Here is the declaration for `buyFeature:onComplete:onCancelled`:

```
- (void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureId
         onComplete:(void (^)(NSString* purchasedFeature, NSData*purchasedReceipt, NSArray* availableDownloads)) completionBlock
        onCancelled:(void (^)(void)) cancelBlock;
```

So, just to start with, we see that `onComplete:` requires a block that takes three parameters. But you are supplying a block with no parameters. Thus, the compiler rightly complains that you forgot the block parameters.

In effect, the problem has nothing whatever to do with MKStoreKit. The problem is that you don't know C - in particular, you don't know the syntax for blocks. I would suggest reading [Apple's explanation of this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html).

Comment: Right. Interesting. I don't understand why in the official tutorial (the one presented by the kit's dev) only one parameters is shown (http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/) ? It doesn't deal with purchasedReceipt and availableDownloads.

Comment: I don't know; I don't know anything about MKStoreKit. But _you_ didn't include _any_ parameters, so either way (regardless of whether it wants one or three parameters) it wouldn't compile.

Comment: By the way, they should not be using the prefix `MK` for their names. That prefix (and all other two-character capital letter prefixes) belongs to Apple.